# How to change material stepper line style with labelPosition="bottom"

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wont to create style like this:

[image]

I tried to set style for all lines under edited steps, but there is lines outside of mat-step-headers.

```
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header {
    &[ng-reflect-state='edit'] + .mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
               border-top-width: 4px;
               border-top-color: blue;
    }
}
```

this is the result:

[image]

So, how can i make it?

Answer (score 2):

head and end of the line in the header. you can use this classes with reflect state.

```css
.mat-stepper-label-position-bottom .mat-horizontal-stepper-header:not(:first-child)::before, [dir=rtl] .mat-stepper-label-position-bottom .mat-horizontal-stepper-header:not(:last-child)::before { 
  border-top-width: 4px;
  border-top-color: blue;
}

.mat-stepper-label-position-bottom .mat-horizontal-stepper-header:not(:last-child)::after, [dir=rtl] .mat-stepper-label-position-bottom .mat-horizontal-stepper-header:not(:first-child)::after {
  border-top-width: 4px;
  border-top-color: blue;
}

.mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
  border-top-width: 4px;
  border-top-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution, maybe will help someone:

scss

```
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header {
    height: 72px !important;
    padding: 0 10px !important;
    .mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
        top: 10px !important;
    }
    .mat-step-label {
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 15px;
        width: 200px !important;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        text-align: center;
    }
    &::before {
        width: 0;
    }
}
.selectedIndex0 {
}
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
    .selectedIndex#{$i} {
        @extend .selectedIndex#{$i - 1};
        ::ng-deep .mat-stepper-horizontal-line:nth-child(#{$i * 2}) {
            border-top-width: 4px !important;
            border-top-color: #3f51b5 !important;
        }
    }
}
```

and adding `[class]="'selectedIndex' + stepper.selectedIndex + ' mat-stepper-label-position-bottom'"` to `mat-horizontal-stepper` tag

Answer (score 0):

> change below line in html

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper ngClass="{{ 'last-edited-step-' + stepper.selectedIndex }}">
```

Here will be the steppers

> and add below scss code to scss file.

```
@mixin styleStepLine($index) {
  .mat-horizontal-stepper-header {
    &+.mat-stepper-horizontal-line:nth-child(#{$index}) {
      height: 2px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #17459b 0%, #0c76c3 51%, #02a8ec 100%);
    }
  }
}

.last-edited-step-1 {
  @include styleStepLine(2);
}

.last-edited-step-2 {
  @include styleStepLine(2);
  @include styleStepLine(4);
}
```

> It will helps to change line of mat-stepper in angular according to the progress of stepper